# Spring Integration and Spring Batch transaction manager collision

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-integration, spring-jdbc

I am using spring integration flow to read file from a file server. My app will be running with multiple instances. I want to insure that each instance processes any file only once. Here is what I am using so far:

1. SFTP Inbound Channel Adapter (to read messages based on a poll)
2. SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter with JdbcMetadataStore (persistence store)
3. Transformer (to convert Message of type File to JobLaunchRequest)
4. @ServiceActivator to  launch Spring Batch job with JobLaunchingGateway

Spring docs suggest using Transaction Manager with JdbcMetadataStore since it uses transactional putIfAbsent queries.

So I am providing PlatformTransactionManager bean in my Java DSL Spring integration flow. I am also using the same transaction manager in my Spring Batch step (chunk() method).

Problem: I am getting the following error "***Existing transaction detected in JobRepository. Please fix this and try again***"

Is there a better approach to fix/design this flow or a simple fix to this error?

It works with Redis Metadata Store since that one is non transactional. My overall problem is that with JdbcMetadataStore I get unique constrain violation when my multiple instances poll at exact same second and ends up getting same file to be put in metadata store table in my database.

By the way I am using Postgres db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options.

See `AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean`:

```
/**
 * Flag to determine whether to check for an existing transaction when a JobExecution
 * is created. Defaults to true because it is usually a mistake, and leads to problems
 * with restartability and also to deadlocks in multi-threaded steps.
 * @param validateTransactionState the flag to set
 */
public void setValidateTransactionState(boolean validateTransactionState
```

(Not sure, though, how to set that via annotation).

You can change the input channel type from `DirectChannel` to `QueueChannel` or `ExecutorChannel`. This way a transaction on the file polling is going to be committed before message has reached `JobLaunchingGateway`.

Comment: Thanks Artem, I switched to QueueChannel and it solved the transaction issue. Now there is another problem. "ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "int_metadata_store_pk" I guess spring suggesting to use transaction manager with JDBC Metadata Store does not fix the multiple instance putIfAbsent call for accept once filter.

Comment: RedisMetadataStore returns true or false for putIfAbsent and does not throw exception with multiple instances grabbing a file at exact same second. JdbcMetadataStore just fails, I mean it does the job but with exception. One of the instances do process the file but other ones fail with duplicate key exception. Do you know any way around this?

Comment: I guess one way would be to extend SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter and override accept method to acquire lock before making call to putIfAbsent. That way one only one instance performs same query at a given time.

By the way the precision timing is just to make the app more safe over fixed delay, which could collide in multiple instance environment.

Comment: Can you share that exception for `int_metadata_store_pk`, because we really have that `DuplicateKeyException` caught in the `JdbcMetadataStore.tryToPutIfAbsent()`. So, perhaps PostgreSQL throws something else on the matter...

Comment: In case of `DefaultLockRepository` we catch `DataIntegrityViolationException` which is a super class of the `DuplicateKeyException`. So, probably an error translator doesn't work properly on PostgreSQL ...

Comment: Yes. That's the one. We have to follow whatever `DataIntegrityViolationException` Javadocs say. So, I'll `JdbcMetadataStore` soon enough.

Comment: Sorry do you still need the stack trace? and you will update JDBC Metadata Store?

Comment: I updated it yesterday: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/commit/676733ccf7b9e67ad9a579178f4d8139d9276f11. Let's hope that your PostgreSQL really throws something what is translated into that `DataIntegrityViolationException`! The release is next week.

Comment: What version will have this change?

Comment: `6.1.7`, `6.2.3` and `6.3.0-M2`